# Stopping time of a damped pendulum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, time

I'm interested in how long it would take for a damped pendulum to stop moving. I've found that the general
form of a function $x(t)$ which returns the angular displacement of the pendulum given some time $t$ is:

$$x(t)=A_0e^{-\frac{b}{2m} t} \cos{(\omega t+\varphi)},$$
where $A_0$ is the initial angular displacement of the pendulum, $b$ is the damping constant, $m$ is the mass of the pendulum, $\omega$ is the natural angular frequency of the damped pendulum and $\varphi$ is some constant some value (I must admit, I do not know what this value means yet. Any help would be nice).

Essentially, I want to find some value $T$ such that $x(T + t)=0$ for all $t\ge0$. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Related [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583056/pendulum-how-to-measure-the-value-of-the-decay-constant-tau-experimentally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see from the exponential term $e^{-\frac{b}{2m}t}$ that the amplitude in this model of the pendulum’s motion never actually reaches zero.

It is possible to ask how long it takes the amplitude to reach some small value - say one hundredth or one thousandth of $A_0$ - but it is not meaningful to ask how long it takes the pendulum to stop completely.

Of course, we know that real pendulums do stop eventually, but this just tells us this exponential decay model is not a completely accurate description of a pendulum’s motion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you happen to know what the $\varphi$ represents physically?

Comment: The $\varphi$ represents the phase.

Comment: Would it have a physical representation such as the damping constant $b$?

Comment: @SeanXie The phase $\phi$ tells you where the pendulum is in its swing when $t=0$. If $\phi=0$ then the pendulum is at one end of its swing when $t=0$. If $\phi=90^o$ or $\pi // 2$ radians then the pendulum is at its central point when $t=0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification :)